# Count(*) -1 in the denominator - sql

Tags: sql, date, average, datediff

Can someone please help me with the count(*)-1 in the denominator here - why is -1 needed in the query below

Q: the query helps in finding average days between orders for each customer

A: select CustomerID
, cast(DATEDIFF(dd, min(OrderDate), max(OrderDate)) as decimal) / (count(*) - 1) as [Avg_day]
from Orders
group by CustomerID
having count(*) > 1

Answer (score 2):

Consider a sequence of times such as:

```
A........B........C........D
```

You want to find the average time between two events.  Well, this is defined as:

```
( (B - A) + (C - B) + (D - C) ) / 3
```

You can expand this out:

```
B/3 - A/3 + C/3 - B/3 + D/3 - C/3
```

Notice that Bs and Cs cancel out, so you are left with:

```
-A/3 + D/3
```

which is

```
(D - A) / 3
```

That is your original expression.  The `3` is one less than the number of points you started with.

This generalizes to any number of events.  The divisor is one less than the total number of events (really, the number of adjacent pairs).